# Generic method called with base type

Tags: c#, .net

I have a situation like this:

```
public class Foo{}

public interface IBar<in TEx>
    where TEx : Exception
{
    Foo Build(TEx ex);
}

public class FooFactory{
    public Foo Create<TEx>(TEx ex) where TEx : Exception{
         // blah
    }
}
```

If I call the `FooFactory.Create` method passing any Exception type everything works. Things start to get wierd when I do something like this:

```
// this is an external class, cannot be changed.
public class ExceptionContext{
    public Exception Ex{get; set;}
}

var context = new ExceptionContext(){ Ex = new MyCustomException (); }
var factory = new FooFactory();
var fooInstance = factory.Create(context.Ex);
```

When I call `FooFactory.Create()`, the passed exception is always of type `System.Exception`, not `MyCustomException` as I would expect.

Any suggestion?

EDIT:
just to give a little bit of context, I am trying to run exception-specific code inside the OnException(ExceptionContext context) method of a custom implementation of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IExceptionFilter .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When I call `FooFactory.Create()`, the passed exception is always of type `System.Exception`

That's because the *static type* of `ExceptionContext.Ex` is `Exception`.  The generic method is bound at *compile time*, which has no knowledge that the dynamic *runtime type* of the exception is different.

The next best bet is to specify the runtime type at compile time using an explicit cast:

```
var fooInstance = factory.Create((MyCustomException)context.Ex);
```

Which obviously *assumes* that the runtime type is `MyCustomException`. If it's not, you'll get an invalid cast exception.

You can also use `dynamic` to defer the method resolution to runtime:

```
dynamic fooInstance = factory.Create((dynamic)context.Ex);
```

The risk here is that anything that uses `fooInstance` will by dynamic as well, so you get no compile-time safety, and any errors (misspelled names, wrong parameter types) won't be discovered until run-time.

**EDIT**

Removed this part of the answer since `ExceptionContext` is not under the OPs control.

<strike>You *could* make `ExceptionContext` generic as well:</strike>

```
public class ExceptionContext<TEx> 
    where TEx : Exception
{
    public <TEx> Ex{get; set;}
}

var context = new ExceptionContext<MyCustomException>(){ Ex = new MyCustomException (); }
var factory = new FooFactory();
var fooInstance = factory.Create(context.Ex);
```

Or add a constructor if you want to use parameter inference:

```
public class ExceptionContext<TEx> 
    where TEx : Exception
{
    public ExceptionContext(TEx exception)
    {
        this.Ex = exception;
    {

    public <TEx> Ex{get; set;}
}

var context = new ExceptionContext(new MyCustomException());
var factory = new FooFactory();
var fooInstance = factory.Create(context.Ex);
```

But it's not clear if that is appropriate for your program overall.

Comment: well, as you said, that would work only if the runtime type is MyCustomException. What if I want to run this code whatever the exception type is? I mean, I don't know at COMPILE time what would be the exception type, that's why I would like to use a generic interface...

Comment: using dynamic as you suggested won't solve the problem, the static type passed to the factory will always be System.Exception :(

Comment: factory.Create((dynamic)context.Ex); worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @MizRaeL Great.  I  though making the return type dynamic would be enough, but it makes sense that you have to make the input parameter dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

Consider making your `ExceptionContext` class generic as well:

```
public class ExceptionContext<TEx> where TEx : Exception
{
    public TEx Ex{get; set;}
}
```

In this way, the most derived type of the exception is preserved, rather than the most base type (in your case, `System.Exception`).

The exception to this rule is, of course, when your exception is an instance of `System.Exception`.

Comment: unfortunately I can't. The ExceptionContext is actually the one provided by Microsoft in  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters. 
I have edited the question just to clarify things a little.